# how to get the list of managers of a group?

Tags: apex, force.com, salesforce-id

Using apex code in SalesForce:

```
CollaborationGroup gp = [Select OwnerId, Id 
                         From CollaborationGroup 
                         Where Name = 'Group_ReadOnly'];
```

how to get the list of managers of a group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx for your answer :-)

```
List<CollaborationGroupMember> managers = [Select MemberId 
                          From CollaborationGroupMember 
                          Where CollaborationGroupId = :gp.Id 
                          And CollaborationRole = 'Admin'];
```

there's a bug in the documentation. The valid values for CollaborationRole are 'Standard' and 'Admin', not 'Member' and 'Manager'.

[enter link description here](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Chatter-and-Chatter-API/How-to-get-the-list-of-managers-of-a-group/m-p/631899)

thx

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to use the subquery:

```
Select Id, Name, (Select Id 
                  From GroupMembers 
                  Where CollaborationRole = 'Manager') 
From CollaborationGroup
Where Name = 'Group_ReadOnly'
```

**Update**

I think the better way to get the member ids is to query the `CollaborationGroupMember` object:

```
Set<Id> ids = (new Map<Id, CollaborationGroupMember>([Select Id 
                              From CollaborationGroupMember
                              Where CollaborationGroup.Name = 'Group_ReadOnly' 
                              And CollaborationRole = 'Manager'])).keySet();
```

Comment: thx for your answer :-)

i tried white this code but i have an error! 

   List<Id> managers2 = [Select Id 
           From CollaborationGroup gp,CollaborationGroupMember gm
                 Where gp.Name = 'Group_ReadOnly' AND 
                                gm.CollaborationRole ='Manager' AND 
                                gp.Id = gm.CollaborationGroupId];

error:  unexpected token: 'gm.CollaborationGroupId'

thx

Comment: @KhaledZero Updated my code. This is a oneliner set query.

Comment: tank you @mastOr